# How to get fix for: Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, libuv

If a run my current *nodejs* project, it crashes as soon as FireStore is accessed (the problem started when I moved to a new Windows laptop):

```
Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time, file c:\ws\deps\uv\src\win\core.c, line 309
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221226505
```

The cause has been identified to be a VS compiler bug affecting [libuv](https://libuv.org/) and has been fixed in *libuv* with a workaround:

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1633

To the best of my understanding, *libuv* is a dependency of *nodejs*. The relationship to FireStore seems to be more of a coincidence. So how can I get a working *nodejs* environment that incorporates the fix (or is not affected by the bug)?

(I'd rather not go the WSL route proposed by others as I would need to considerably change my development setup.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually for me also got the same error. This **[GitHub](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/2470#issuecomment-649541821)** issue made me to solve the problem. 
it says like

> Clock synchronization, obviously, shouldn't help in most cases. I've
> build 14.4.0 version with this [patch](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/commit/796744869669842bd5405a71de8ba60b1556fc24), it works. Maybe it'll help
> someone. Simply, download [node.zip](https://github.com/nodejs/help/files/4831517/node.zip) and replace node.exe in folder,
> where NodeJS 14.4.0 is installed.